# Spring Webflux and Keycloak JWT rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak, spring-webflux

I am building a userinfo endpoint on my Webflux rest api, how do  I access the access_token passed in through the Authorization header in the rest call. Also need a similar endpoint to update the user.

All the examples I have found with latest spring 5/boot 2 are about securing a webapp.

```
@GetMapping("/api/user-info")
    public Map userInfo(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.getAuthorizedClient(authentication);
        Map userAttributes = Collections.emptyMap();

        String userInfoEndpointUri = authorizedClient
                                    .getClientRegistration()
                                    .getProviderDetails()
                                    .getUserInfoEndpoint()
                                    .getUri();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoEndpointUri)) {
            // userInfoEndpointUri is optional for OIDC Clients
            userAttributes = WebClient.builder()
                    .filter(oauth2Credentials(authorizedClient))
                    .build()
                    .get()
                    .uri(userInfoEndpointUri)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Map.class)
                    .block();
        }

        return userAttributes;
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizedClient getAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
        return this.authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName());
    }

    private ExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Credentials(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(
                clientRequest -> {
                    ClientRequest authorizedRequest = ClientRequest.from(clientRequest)
                            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue())
                            .build();
                    return Mono.just(authorizedRequest);
                });
    }
```

OAuth2AuthenticationToken object defined in the method is null which is understandable but not sure what else need configuring.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the header the standard way? I mean, without using the Spring Oauth library.

Comment: I couldn't be arsed with Spring, I ended up using Vertx. Sometimes Spring just gets in the way.

Comment: Have you looked into this, Section 82.2.1 Client Token Relay in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Have you looked into this Token Relay or TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory from the Spring Cloud Gateway project yet? 

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RELEASE/multi/multi__more_detail.html